# Forensic image of a VPS

Tags: forensics

Is it possible to acquire forensic image of a VPS without rebooting it ? Are any signs to an end user that it's VPS was imaged by the VPS provider ?

Comment: Do you mean creating a snapshot for the VPS?

Comment: @mootmoot yes copying disk image

Comment: Check your cloud service provider terms and condition.  Don't use them if you don't trust them. Yes,  it is possible to create snapshot without shutting down, you can even do that with Virtualbox.

Comment: Well, some cloud services allow you to encrypt the snapshot. But.....well, it is about trust.

Comment: Many VPS providers allow you to access the console from where you can perform manual installation via PXE boot. This way you can install Linux from over internet (from mirror) and choose encrypted filesystem which makes imaging futile. The only thing they will be to do would be taking RAM snapshot and reading the key which is a bit harder.